# Zend Form Element Row needs either an id or class set through Zend_Config_Ini

Tags: forms, zend-form, zend-form-element, zend-config

I have the following default decorators in a Zend_Config_Ini to set up my form:

```
elementDecorators.viewHelper.decorator = "ViewHelper"
elementDecorators.label.decorator = "Label"
elementDecorators.errors.decorator = "Errors"
elementDecorators.htmlTag.decorator = "HtmlTag"
elementDecorators.htmlTag.options.tag = "li"
```

I have the following element definition also in the Zend_Config_Ini:

```
elements.username.type = "text"
elements.username.options.label = "Username:"
elements.username.options.required = true
```

and the following output is produced:

```
<li>
    <label for="username" class="required">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" />
</li>
```

Now what I need to know is, how do I (through the ini config file preferably), set the id or class of the LI tag?  I would like the following output:

```
<li id="form-username-element"> ... </li>
```

or

```
<li class="form-2col"> ... </li>
```

**Update:
I was able to get it by overriding all the decorators in the element config itself like this:**

```
elements.username.options.decorators.viewHelper.decorator = "ViewHelper"
elements.username.options.decorators.label.decorator = "Label"
elements.username.options.decorators.errors.decorator = "Errors"
elements.username.options.decorators.htmlTag.decorator = "HtmlTag"
elements.username.options.decorators.htmlTag.options.tag = "li"
elements.username.options.decorators.htmlTag.options.class = "username-row-element"
```

So that will work, however creates a lot of duplication as that would have to go onto every element (with the single change of the last line which would be the class setting itself).  So what I am NOW wondering, is, from the ini file, is there a way to just override the class name using the default decorators (rather than having to duplicate all of the decorators for each element)?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest thing to do is create your own Decorator. For instance, I've created an ElementWrap decorator, which wraps each element with a div and adds the necessary class and id. It could look something like this:

```
class Form_Decorator_ElementWrap extends Zend_Form_Decorator_Abstract
{
    public function render($content)
    {
        $element = $this->getElement();
        if($this->getOption('openOnly')) {
            return '<div class="'.$this->getClass().'" id="'.$this->getId().'">' . $content;
        } else if($this->getOption('closeOnly')) {
            return $content . PHP_EOL . '</div>' . PHP_EOL;
        } else {
            return '<div class="'.$this->getClass().'" id="'.$this->getId().'">' . $content . '</div>';
        }
    }

    public function getClass()
    {
        $element = $this->getElement();
        $classes = array(
            'field_wrap',
            'field_' . strtolower(substr(strrchr($element->getType(), '_'), 1)),
            $this->getOption('class'),
        );
        if($element->hasErrors()) {
            $classes[] = 'field_error';
        }
        if($elementClass = $element->getAttrib('class')) {
            $classes[] = $elementClass;
        }
        return implode(' ', array_filter($classes));
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return 'fieldwrap-' . $element->getId();
    }
}
```